# How to select a number?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

return:

```
CentOS Linux release 5.6.1804 (Core)
```

how do I select the first number I've only tried

```
cat /etc/redhat-release | awk '{print $4}'
```

and this gives me back:

```
5.6.1804
```

but I just want the first number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo 'CentOS Linux release 5.6.1804 (Core)'|awk '{print $4}'|awk -F '.' '{print $1}'
5
```

Need I say more?

Comment: @ortiga Don't forget to select one answer you like the most and accept it. Personally, I would select the lsb_release answer, but my answer is closest to what you originally did.

Answer (score 2):

If your CentOS machine has `redhat-lsb` or `redhat-lsb-core` installed:

```
lsb_release -sr | cut -d '.' -f 1
```

This would get the release version (only) using the `lsb_release` command and then `cut` out the bit before the first dot.

On a `16.04` Ubuntu machine:

```
$ lsb_release -sr | cut -d '.' -f 1
16
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **awk**:

```
awk -F '[ .]' '{print $4}' /etc/redhat-release
```

Using **sed**:

```
sed -E 's/[ Aa-Zz]*([0-9]+).*/\1/' /etc/redhat-release
```

Using **grep**:

```
grep -Eo ' [0-9]' /etc/redhat-release
```

Comment: There's also `/etc/os-release`

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways, here is one of those:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release | cut -d " " -f4 | cut -d . -f1
```

The easier way would be using something that is prepared just for that:

```
[user@server]$ source /etc/os-release && echo $CENTOS_MANTISBT_PROJECT_VERSION
7
```

Answer (score 0):

sed -Ee's/^.* ([0-9.]+) .*$/\1/' /etc/redhat-release |cut -f1,1 -d.

Sed command extracts the whole version number (same as your AWK, so you could use that as well) and the second extracts the first field from that using '.' as the separator.

so you could also use:
awk '{print $4}' /etc/redhat-release |cut -f1,1 -d.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something akin to this.  On my RH7 box:

```
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.5 (Maipo)

$ cut -f 7 -d " " /etc/redhat-release
7.5

$ cut -f 7 -d " " /etc/redhat-release | IFS=. read MAJOR MINOR RELEASE

$ echo $MAJOR $MINOR $RELEASE
7 5

$
```

Now you have all the components of the build in an env var to be referneced at you leisure.  There are more sophisticated ways to get the original data, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question, which is just extracting the components of a dotted version string.